# Redirecting html page when closing iframe include in that html page

Tags: html, iframe, redirect

I am having 3 html pages.

1. Home page.
2. Login  page.
3. success page.

Inside the home I have an iframe of second specified login page. In that iframe(login page) when I submit or close iframe my iframe should be closed and also home page should be redirected to the sucess page.
For redirecting parent page of the iframe what should I do?

Comment: How do you handle validation errors? e.g. the username or password is incorrect? This will affect the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try with javascript

```
parent.location = "http://site.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the target of the form.

```
<form action="login.php" target="_top">
```